# Appending a byte to String in java using escape sequence

Tags: java, string, escaping, append, byte

I wish to append a byte i.e. 16 = 0x10 to a String, using escape sequence to do it in single line of code:

```
String appendedString = new String('\16'+"String");
```

This results in a hex representation of appendedString = 0x0E,0x74,0x72,0x69,0x6E,0x67

using a \2 like this:

```
String appendedString = new String('\2'+"String");
```

works fine resulting in a hex representation of appendedString = 0x02,0x74,0x72,0x69,0x6E,0x67

using a \10:

```
String appendedString = new String('\10'+"String");
```

results in a hex representation of appendedString = 0x08,0x74,0x72,0x69,0x6E,0x67

Someone may kindly explain this and suggest a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an octal escape.  The [Java Language Specification, Section 3.10.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6), defines escapes, including octal escapes.

> OctalEscape:
>       \ OctalDigit
>       \ OctalDigit OctalDigit
>       \ ZeroToThree OctalDigit OctalDigit

So, `\16` is the character `14` in decimal, or `0x0E` in hexadecimal.

The character `\2` remains `2` in decimal and hexadecimal.

The character `\10` is `8` in decimal, or `0x08` in hexadecimal.

To use hexadecimal escapes, use a Unicode escape, defined in [JLS Section 3.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3):

> UnicodeEscape:
>
> ```
> \ UnicodeMarker HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit
> ```
>
> UnicodeMarker:
>
> ```
> u
> UnicodeMarker u
> ```

such as `\u0016`, `\u0002`, and `\u0010`.

Answer (score 2):

`\10` is in *octal* which is why you're getting U+0008.

I don't believe there are any escape formats which use decimal; I'd suggest using the `\uxxxx` format, or specific escape sequences for supported characters (`\r`, `\n` etc). So for the second case you could use `\u000a` - or just use `\n` in this case. For the first, you'd use `\u0010`.

See [section 3.10.6 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) for more details about escape sequences.

I'd also strongly recommend that you stop thinking of these as bytes - they're *characters* (or UTF-16 code units, if you want to be really precise).

Comment: ahan, I was missing out the fact that Java considers that as an octal. Thanks

Comment: I’ve always wondered why there weren’t any escape formats which use base-10 numbers for the code point — and I mean in any language I can think of.